# Finding the period of an infinite length pendulum

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, earth

What would be the period of a [pendulum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pendulum) with an infinite length, assuming a non-rotating Earth? The answer is not infinity.

Comment: Well, the limiting case of a mathematical pendulum of finite length would suggest that the period would tend to infinity. If you say it's not infinity, what kinds of assumptions are we allowed to make here? I mean, an infinitely long pendulum would rupture under the weight of its string. Is that supposed to be the answer?

Comment: I presume you are expected to calculate the result not in a uniform field as we do with reasonably sized pendulums (in which case the period does grow without bound) but with the full spherical field and neglecting the mass of the rod.

Comment: @dmckee how does the field falling off with height help? Wouldn't this "softening" just make the problem worse?

Comment: @NowIGetToLearnWhatAHeadIs It's not that it falls off with height, it's that there is a residual change in *direction* of the field. You can't use the analysis that we use on the finite length pendulum because the rod always points in the same direction.

Comment: Heck, while we're at it, what if the Earth is rotating infinitely fast instead?

Comment: I think the part about nonrotating earth is to avoid the engineering issue of a tangled and ever shortening pendulum :X

Comment: either way it doesn't make sense--a pendulum at infinite distance experiences no return force because it has zero potential energy.

Comment: @gregsan No, it expereinces a return force because the field from the Earth doesn't point uniformly down (except in a small lab), it points toward the center of the Earth. I'll undelete my answer later on if you want to see how I worked it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the pendulum bob, moves in a straight line, and if we presume that the bob is effectively in a vacuum, or is heavy enough for air resistance to not matter, and the path is basically at the earth surface, it would seem that the period is effectively independent of the pendulum length for lengths many times the earth radius.

I can't be bothered to work out the answer, which should be relatively simple; but I am prepared to give you a WAG answer.

I believe the period is 84 minutes or thereabouts, provided of course the amplitude is a small value compared to the earth radius.

Now, 84 minutes just happens to be the period of a simple pendulum, whose length is equal to the earth radius.  It is also the orbital period of an earth satellite orbiting essentially at the earth surface (no air resistance).

Moreover, if you drill a hole between any two points on the earth surface, close enough together that the center of the hole is not too much below the surface as a fraction of the earth radius, then the transit time for a round trip between those two points in say a straight evacuated frictionless tube, is also 84 minutes.

So I don't distinguish between the tube case, and the infinite pendulum case, so I say the answer is 84 minutes.

People who make inertial stable platforms (gyro stabilized are familiar with a "hum" instability in their systems, that has an 84 minute period.

Answer (score 0):

I choose to put the "centered" position of the bob over the north pole, and have the z-axis point upward through the pole. The bob swings in the x-z plane, with it's point of closest approach at radius $r_c = r_e (1 + \epsilon)$.

The gravitational force acting on the bob, in the limit of small oscillations is $ -mg(\hat{z} + \frac{x}{r_c}\hat{x}) $, and the rod provides $+mg\hat{z}$ leaving a residual of $F = -x\frac{mg}{r_c}\hat{x}$ so this arrangement *is* a harmonic oscillator with $k = \frac{mg}{r_c}$.

The usual solution applies giving $\omega = \sqrt{\frac{k}{m}} = \sqrt{\frac{g}{r_c}}$. That gives me a bit over 5000 seconds for small oscillations near the surface. This agrees with [George's analysis](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/77570/520).

Cute problem. As usual the process is more important here than the result.